# Decode base64 mixed with html In PHP

Tags: php

I'm using `base64_decode` in php in order to decode a message content.
My message content is mixed with html, english and base64 encoding

Is there any way to decode the message to plain html?

example:

```
 <div dir=3D"ltr">
   <div dir=3D"rtl">=D7=94=D7=90=D7=9D =D7=99=D7=A9 =D7=97=D7=
=93=D7=A9 =D7=91=D7=A0=D7=95=D7=A9=D7=90?<br clear=3D"all"></div> 
   <div>DNS ==D7=9B=D7=91=D7=A8 =D7=A2=D7=95=D7=93=D7=9B=D7=9F.</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The attributes look odd `dir=3D"ltr"`?

Comment: dir=3D"ltr" is just how i retrive it from gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the simple solution, used two decoding methods.

```
  quoted_printable_decode(base64_decode($trim4));
  quoted_printable_decode($trim4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run the php command:

```
base64_decode ( string $data [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : string;
```

After that just generate the html code using Javascript

See [php.net documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Comment: i don't think it got nothing to do with my question.

Comment: well, i supose you want to decode the following:

<div dir=3D"rtl"> **=D7=94=D7=90=D7=9D =D7=99=D7=A9 =D7=97=D7=
=93=D7=A9 =D7=91=D7=A0=D7=95=D7=A9=D7=90?** <br clear=3D"all"></div> 
   <div> **DNS ==D7=9B=D7=91=D7=A8 =D7=A2=D7=95=D7=93=D7=9B=D7=9F.** </div>


So you can retrieve the innerHTML and run it trough the decoding function, right

Comment: can you give me a more specific example for the usage?

Comment: okay, so you have got to give your `div` an `id` like this:
`<div id="firstDiv" dir=3D"rtl">=D7=94=D7=90=D7=9D =D7=99=D7=A9 =D7=97=D7=
=93=D7=A9 =D7=91=D7=A0=D7=95=D7=A9=D7=90?<br clear=3D"all"></div> 
   <div id="secondDiv">DNS ==D7=9B=D7=91=D7=A8 =D7=A2=D7=95=D7=93=D7=9B=D7=9F.</div>`

Then you have to get the elements innerHtml, like so:

`<script>
function myFunction() {
  var firstDivEncoded = document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML;
  var secondDivEncoded = document.getElementById("secondDiv").innerHTML;
}
</script>`

store js var in PHP as `$dataFromScript`.

Comment: then you use php to decode it:

`base64_decode ( $dataFromScript );`

Comment: yeah but its not the point, its just an example of mixed code, the base64 code can be outside a div or just standalone code. thanks for the effort.